# get loudness level from raw data recieved from microphone in DirectShow

Tags: c++, audio, directshow

How I can get loudness level from raw data received from microphone in DirectShow?

IMediaSample keep data in bytes. And how I can read this bytes and get something?

Comment: What did the documentation tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loudness is an aural quality, not a physic formula. There are many many definitions for it.

It's a also a temporal value. As a consequence, this value changes during the time.

The simplest implementation I remember I had seen some years ago, was simply putting a time out on the maximum value of the amplitude. But the log of the amplitude is **surely** better to approximate the ear sensitivity much closer.

You can also consider the power of the signal ( signal * signal ... but there are also more definitions that takes into account the frequency spectrum components...).

It's kitchen recipes. Choose the simplest.

**Edit**: it seems my answer was too fast and fuzzy, I probably mistake Volume and Loudness. [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness) states there are units for measuring loudness. [Sone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sone) and [Phon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon).

Answer (score 1):

You need to process data to calculate loudness out of raw bytes. One of the method is defined in [BS.1770 : Algorithms to measure audio programme loudness and true-peak audio level](https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BS.1770/en) specification and describes the algorithm involved.